# Trying to implement flexbox to fill remaining height of webpage, but not functioning in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have been trying to use flexbox to auto-size certain divs to 'fill' the remaining height on a webpage, but in Chrome (presumably due to the height being set by the flexbox, and not explicitly), I can't control the overflow of the content properly. This is a weird question to try to put into words, so I'll give an example:

```
<div style="height:250px">   
    <div class="flex-container-vertical" style="height: 100%">
        <div class="header">
            HEADER
        </div>
        <div class="fill-remainder" style="overflow:hidden">
            <div class="flex-container-vertical" style="height: 100%">
                <div class="secondheader">
                  SECOND HEADER
                </div>
                <div class="fill-remainder" style="overflow:auto">
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

.flex-container-vertical {
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.fill-remainder {
    flex: 2;
}

.header {
    background: salmon;
    height:50px;
}

.secondheader {
    background: lavender;
    height: 50px;
}

.footer {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 50px;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqJQB

If you open the above codepen in most browsers, the overflow of the "BODYCONTENT" text is scrollable. However, if it is opened in Google Chrome, it is not.

In the following example, the overflow works properly in Chrome, but it is no longer set by flexbox, so the 'fill remaining' height feature I'm trying to implement is eliminated.

```
<div style="height:250px">   
    <div class="flex-container-vertical" style="height: 100%">
        <div class="header">
            HEADER
        </div>
        <div class="fill-remainder" style="overflow:hidden; height:150px">
            <div class="flex-container-vertical" style="height: 100%">
                <div class="secondheader">
                  SECOND HEADER
                </div>
                <div class="fill-remainder" style="overflow:auto">
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                    BODYCONTENT<br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

.flex-container-vertical {
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.fill-remainder {
    flex: 2;
}

.header {
    background: salmon;
    height:50px;
}

.secondheader {
    background: lavender;
    height: 50px;
}

.footer {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 50px;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOrweK

It's a long story as to why I have to implement things this way, but someone wrote the code before me and certain parts of the actual content are loaded dynamically and won't work properly with a table layout. I should also add that I cannot use position:absolute, because it has weird behavior on mobile and I have been told not to.

Thanks to anyone with suggestions!

Comment: I believe you needed your flex containers to reach the bottom of the page, right? See my answer.

Comment: This was the exact behavior I was looking for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqZjP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the overflow of fill-remainder to auto.

```
<div class="fill-remainder" style="overflow:auto">
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdqJEr

Comment: Oh no wait.. I can't have the overflow set to auto in my case, I need the scroll feature to be on the inner element. :(

Comment: Hmm.. sort of. unfortunately, that example doesn't work in firefox. I might be able to make something work between mine and yours, though.

Comment: There, I got it to work using yours. Thanks! (I wasn't able to try it until today).

Comment: I thought you wanted to cover the whole page? I fixed it perfectly: http://codepen.io/01/pen/YXbxNm

Comment: No, the problem wasn't that it wouldn't fill the height. It would do that without the height being set on the outer element to begin with. The problem was that it wasn't working on Google Chrome

Comment: You saved my ass never thought I'd get this working. Tried everything with different strategies and IE10 always failed. Table layout codepen: http://codepen.io/dmcquillan314/pen/VjWgYy  Flexbox codepen: http://codepen.io/dmcquillan314/pen/LkzVAz?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/01/pen/YXbxNm/)

### HTML

You require some behavior that flexbox can provide, it's just you must remember 3 flex-container properties that allow it to manipulate it's children properly.

1. You should always use: [`justify-content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/) when your `flex-direction` is `row`
2. If `flex-direction` is `column` then use [`align-items`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)
3. If your'e are going to have more then one `row` or `column`, then use [`align-content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/)

So I applied what was previously mentioned (except the align-content). I didn't need `justify-content` really but I always use that and `align-items` together because it's convenient for responsive layouts. The important thing is `align-items: stretch` which allows all of your flex-children to reach the bottom of the webpage. I also set your most outer `div` to `height: 100vh` it was originally `250px` I think, so no matter what you'd try, that `250px` `div` would thwart your attempts.

Btw, I changed some class names because they're too long for me to process (lazy brain).

PS, Unless your concerned about Android 4.4 and IE8, the only [**vendor prefixes**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) you need is a set of `-webkit-` for Safari.

```
<div style="height:100vh">   
<div class="flexShell" style="height: 100%">
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="flexFill" style="overflow:hidden">
        <div class="flexShell" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="secondheader">
              SECOND HEADER
            </div>
            <div class="flexFill" style="overflow:auto">
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
                BODYCONTENT<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
 .flexShell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 101%;
}

.flexFill {
  flex: 2;
  height: 101%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flexOver {
  flex: 2;
  height: 101%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.header {
  background: salmon;
  height: 50px;
}

.secondheader {
  background: lavender;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work in google chrome, unfortunately.. You'll notice there is no scrollbar for the "BODYCONTENT"s. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: I only want the innermost "BODYCONTENT"s to be scrollable, not the header for these.. Sorry about all the confusion, I wasn't sure how to explain

Comment: Also, the second codepen I have posted shows the behavior I want, it's just that I want the height for the outer fillremainder class to be set automatically to fill the height of its parent.

Comment: It is difficult to cover every detail, I think there's one more thing I can do.

Comment: @JaredScott I have created the demo that meets all you required even full height. I don't care about the points, but you should take a look at least.